# Sequelize cannot create model with associated model

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model `Category` which has many `Tag` and I want create tags when inserting category data. But every time I call `create` method with `include: 'tags'}` it gives error: `"Tag.categoryId cannot be null"`

Here is my tag model:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class tag extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models['Category'], { as: 'associatedCategory', foreignKey: 'category_id' })
      this.belongsToMany(models.Project, { through: models['ProjectTag'], as: 'TaggedProject' });
    }
  }
  tag.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'categories', // 'categories' is the table name for Category model
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Tag',
    name: 'Tag',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false
  });
  return tag;
};
```

Here is my `Category` model:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Category extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      this.belongsToMany(models['Project'], {
        through: models['ProjectCategory'],
        as: 'Project'
      })
      this.hasMany(models['Tag'], { as: 'tags', foreignKey: 'category_id', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    }
  }
  Category.init({
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Category',
    name: 'Category',
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
  });

  return Category;
};
```

This is the method where I am calling create category:

```
  async create(req, res) {
    const { title, tags = [] } = req.body;

    try {
      const category = await Category.create({
        title,
        tags: tags.map(tag => ({ title: tag }))
      }, {
        include: [{
          model: Tag,
          as: 'tags'
        }]
      });

      return res.status(201).send({ success: true, category });
    } catch (err) {
      showError(err)
    }
  }
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this. I was referencing this documentation: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/

**UPDATE**

So the `create` is working here for nested creation after removing `allowNull: false` from `categoryId` field in `Tag` model.
But also the problem here is when we will be trying to create `Tag` with `allowNull: false`, it will fail to create.

Comment: I guess it is due to mixing of snake_case and camelCase syntax. In assosicate functions you have written **category_id** and in tag.init you have **categoryId**. So sequelize cannot create association with **category_id** as there is no column called __category_id__. Try using **foreginKey: "categoryId"** or change column name in tag to **category_id**. I hope everything will work then.

Comment: But with `underscored` it always generates snake case field, isn't it?

Comment: Yesss it should actually create a column named category_id. Can you once check the tables and see what column is created - category_id or categoryId.

Comment: The `tags` table also has `category_id`